# Jboss 6, Spring & Xerces

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss6.x, xerces, xsd-1.1

I have to validate an xml with xerces(xsd v1.1) inside my webapp(Spring 3), in needs to be deployed in a jboss 6 server. But i am getting an error in the deployment. This doesn't happens in Tomcat. It throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
```

I tried some configuration with jboss-web.xml and jboss-classloading.xml, but i didn't work. Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

The JBoss classloader can be frustrating (the price we pay for security!) But this should help... Place your 1.1 xerves libraries somewhere on the file system and then add the following JVM args when starting JBoss:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/PATH/TO/LIBRARIES
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventFactoryImpl
```